# Decimal expansion in logic Church thesis

Tags: logic, computer-science, computational-complexity

How can we show that the function $n \mapsto e_n$, where $e_n$ is the $n$-th digit in the decimal expansion of $e$, is computable?

I have some idea in terms of Cantor's diag. argument, but I need to think along the lines of writing a series expansion, and Church's thesis.

Can someone produce the series as discussed below? thanks

Comment: Do you really want $n$ to be the $n$th digit? or do you mean for $e_n$ to be the $n$th digit?

Comment: en is the nth digit in e.

Comment: I believe the series to which @Carl refers is $e=\sum_0^{\infty}(n!)^{-1}$.

Comment: Sure, but I dont know how to fit it in with Carl's hint below. Can you please add in the detail below?

Comment: For every $m$, $e$ is between $\sum^m(n!)^{-1}$ and $\epsilon_m+\sum^m(n!)^{-1}$, where "Taylor series with remainder" will give you an upper bound on $\epsilon_m$ --- my guess is you can take $\epsilon_m=2/(m+1)!$, but you should check that. So, if you want the 938th digit of $e$, you just have to choose $m$ large enough to make $\sum^m(n!)^{-1}$ and $\epsilon_m+\sum^m(n!)^{-1}$ agree to 938 places.

Comment: Can you explain the epsilon you chose. I dont see how to justify that. Can you produce an answer below so I can better understand? Thanks

Comment: Can you do some work on your own? Can you even cut'n'paste "Taylor series with remainder" into Google to see what I'm talking about? Anyone throwing around terms like "Cantor's diagonal argument", "series expansion", and "Church's thesis" ought to be able to do a little bit of mathematics on his/her own.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: because $e$ is not a rational number, for each rational number $r$ you can produce a sufficiently good approximation to $e$ to tell whether $e$ is greater than $r$ or less than $r$. The way to make the approximation is to use a series for $e$ for which you can estimate the error for each partial sum.